# Listening to contact email address JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, ajax

I'm developing an application in JS and Node JS which simulating Gmail- gets and sends email.
Now, my question is, when I want to send a new email to one of my contacts, how do I get the list of contacts' email address? I know I should use ajax call but when?
If I call it when initialise the page and get the contacts json then, so I have a problem with the new contacts that may enter to the list in the meanwhile, I mean, the json will never be really updated.
But it sounds bad to create an ajax call each time the user press on 'to' in order to display all the updated contacts..

Hope you understood my question!

thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a number of design choices:

1. You can get the contacts when the page loads and you won't know about any contacts added since the page loaded.
2. Same as #1, but you can offer the user a button to refresh the contact list.
3. You can get the contacts once when the user first presses a button to address the email and you won't know about contacts that change after that.  This makes them slightly more up to date than option #1.
4. You can get the fresh contacts every time the user initiates an addressing operation.  The downsides to this are that you create more requests to your server (possible load at scale) and there might be a slight delay (waiting for the ajax call to complete) before the addressing interface displays.  There also would be a little more bandwidth consumption.
5. You can ask for fresh contacts every time the user initiates an addressing operation, but use the eTag header so that 99% of the time when the contacts haven't changed since before, the server can just return 304 status (for "not modified").  This obviously requires the server to keep track of changes and generate a meaningful eTag header that corresponds to changes, but could reduce bandwidth usage.
6. You can use a webSocket or socket.io connection so that changes to the contacts are automatically pushed to the page and thus the list of contacts in the page is always up-to-date.

---

Since it sounds like you're talking about the user's personal contacts, I'd be surprised if it was a common usage case where the user updates their own contacts while they are in the middle of composing an email.  So, unless you think that will be a common usage, then any of the above options could work just fine depending upon how you prioritize the less common usage case.

I would say you probably start with either #1 or #4 and only do something more involved if you find there's an actual usability issue with any priority.  When developing an app like this, it is important to always keep your eye on the most important things to work on and not over design things that you don't know are actually important.

Comment: Thank you very much! I think #5 is a best solution for my needs. :)

Answer (score -2):

My solution will be try to send user_id=12 to back-end or if multiple users then send users_ids=[12, 13] to back-end. If you want users to be selective on UI then use multi-select check box type UI
If you have information of users at back-end then find user information from database and send emails from back-end asynchronously.
My idea is send emails from back-end, we don't need email information at Front-end .

Comment: I don't understand how this answers the question at all.